# How to trigger a jenkins job without webhook?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job. The Jenkins file is located on my Bitbucket. Now I run my job manually. I need to run my job by trigger when a new commit is pushed.

I wouldn't like to manage the bitbucket webhook, because I use a local version of Jenkins and think opening additional ports and forwarding data is not secure. Also, I wouldn't like to use a time schedule to check for new commit periodically.

How to set up Jenkins to run a job without bitbucket webhooks and schedule - automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are asking is impossible. Jenkins needs to know that a commit has been made. This can only happen if Bitbucket lets Jenkins know using a webhook, or if Jenkins checks Bitbucket from time to time to get that information. Basically there needs to be communication one way or another.

The easiest solution is to have a small separate job that runs every five minutes, calls the Bitbucket API and figures out if there is a new commit. If there is, it can trigger your main build with a list of all commits. If not, it can just end. This way, you won't have your main build filled with aborted builds, and the resource usage is minimal.